# How to Disable Reload CollectionView's animation When Hiding NavBar

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, navigation

I'm getting a strange reload animation when hiding my navBar when I swipe. I'm recreating Twitter's search screen and that required me to nest a collectionView within another collectionView. Since, hidesBarOnSwipe doesn't work on a child collectionView, I had to use this code below. Heres a gif of what it looks:

[image]

```
  func didScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var lastY: CGFloat = 0
    let isScrollingUp = scrollView.contentOffset.y - lastY > 0
    lastY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
//        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
       self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(isScrollingUp, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: that's not how Twitter does it though, so that's one of the main problems. they do it by setting up a UIView that handles various scrollviews or collection/tableviews and then deallocate on swipe left and right so for memory management. their navigation bars are not naviagtion bars, they are uiviews, they have their navigation bars hidden and then use a scrollview for the header where in rests the search bar. they handle this through key-value observation and passing scroll delegates to a single uiview/controller and then handle the offset of the search bar.

Comment: should you wish to implement it the way Twitter does, the closet you'll get is by starting here: https://github.com/maxep/MXSegmentedPager and then rewriting the entire library for MXSegmentedPager to handle regular views and not just the parallax header views. that's as far as i can explain legally. good luck